# Stamp XML as string

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml

my question is very simple.
We are doing tests on XML, and to verify the XML I need to simply stamp it (as a string).
The XML is located in DE sendable, in a field named HTML__XML.
This is my call:

```
%%[
Var @HTML_XML

Set @HTML_XML = AttributeValue("HTML__XML")]%%

%%=v(@HTML_XML)=%%
```

However, performing the call it doesn't show anything. The call normally working with XML (BuildRowSetfromXML, for example) normally works, but I am not able to stamp the raw XML. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should show if you view the source in the VAWP version.  As a workaround, I typically do this for XML debugging output:

```
%%[
var @HTML_XML

set @HTML_XML = AttributeValue("HTML__XML")
set @HTML_XML = replace(replace(@HTML_XML, ">", "&gt;"), "<", "&lt;")

]%%
%%=v(@HTML_XML)=%%
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your feedback. Could you explain why it works only in the VAWP?

Comment: Send preview and VAWP  renders the tags as HTML. it's just easier to view the source on the VAWP.